# Wordpress get attachment image with all sizes

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to add `featured_media` into my API call and i'm not sure on the most efficent way of getting all of the image sizes. I'm thinking something similar to how `wp_get_attachment_metadata()` works but I need the captions and absolute images.

Is there a built in WP function to do this? I know I could iterate through each image size then get the data for each but it seems like this is probably default WP functionality.

Comment: have you seen this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/206534/128983)?

Answer (score 1):

Use this global variable to get all size of images `$_wp_additional_image_sizes` as:

```
global $_wp_additional_image_sizes; 
echo '<pre>'; 
print_r( $_wp_additional_image_sizes ); 
echo '</pre>';
```

The output results will similar to:

```
Array
(
    [thumbnail] => Array
        (
            [width] => 150
            [height] => 150
            [crop] => 1
        )

    [medium] => Array
        (
            [width] => 300
            [height] => 300
            [crop] => 
        )

    [medium_large] => Array
        (
            [width] => 768
            [height] => 0
            [crop] => 
        )

    [large] => Array
        (
            [width] => 1024
            [height] => 1024
            [crop] => 
        )

)
```

If you want to use this global variable in functions.php file then you can hooks to get all size of images.

```
add_action('init', 'get_all_image_sizes');

function get_all_image_sizes(){
    global $_wp_additional_image_sizes; 
    echo '<pre>'; 
    print_r( $_wp_additional_image_sizes ); 
    echo '</pre>';
}
```